# How to move Mesh Collider in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4hOF.png) How can I "move" mesh collider? To add it directly on the house_lvl_4 is not the variant because code won't work.

Maybe there is a chance to "move" it? Or do smth with it?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your visual is offset.

Here are some options:

1. Move your visual to the correct position.
2. Add a mesh collider to the visual and copy/paste it onto the parent (remove from visual after).
3. Add the collider to its own gameobject (using option 2) and move that object.